# Unparseable date with SimpleXml

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I am using Simple XML for XML serialization in my Android project. I have problem with parsing a Date object. I receive an exception:

> Unparseable date: 2012-05-01T08:22:34+02:00

Can anyone help me how to tell Simple XML what the date format is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a timezone at the end of your date. Java can parse timezone offsets, but without the ´:' divider between. So if your date timezone were +0200 instead of +02:00, it should work. You could  run it through a [SimpleDateFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 3):

SimpleXML only supports some `DateFormat`'s, but you can use a custom `Transform` for Dates.

Try my example i posted here: [Parse date with SimpleFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277887/parse-date-with-simpleframework/12492925#12492925)