# Parse date with SimpleFramework

Tags: java, date, simple-framework

I receive an XML response with an attribute which contains following value:

```
Wed Sep 05 10:56:13 CEST 2012
```

I have defined in my model class a field with annotation:

```
@Attribute(name = "regDate")
private Date registerDate;
```

However it throws an exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Sep 05 10:56:13 CEST 2012" (at offset 0)
```

Is it possible to define date format in `SimpleFramework`'s annotations ?

What format should cover this date string ?

Comment: For new readers I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

SimpleXML only supports some `DateFormat`'s:

- **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z**
- **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z**
- **yyyy-MM-dd z**
- **yyyy-MM-dd**

(For the meaning of each character see [SimpleDateFormat API Doc (Java SE 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

However it's possible to write a custom `Transform` who deals with other formats:

### Transform

```
public class DateFormatTransformer implements Transform<Date>
{
    private DateFormat dateFormat;


    public DateFormatTransformer(DateFormat dateFormat)
    {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }



    @Override
    public Date read(String value) throws Exception
    {
        return dateFormat.parse(value);
    }


    @Override
    public String write(Date value) throws Exception
    {
        return dateFormat.format(value);
    }

}
```

### Corresponding Annotation

```
@Attribute(name="regDate", required=true) /* 1 */
private Date registerDate;
```

**Note 1:** `required=true` is optional

### How to use it

```
// Maybe you have to correct this or use another / no Locale
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY", Locale.US);


RegistryMatcher m = new RegistryMatcher();
m.bind(Date.class, new DateFormatTransformer(format));


Serializer ser = new Persister(m);
Example e = ser.read(Example.class, xml);
```

Comment: It seems that only `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z` is supported. Tried others and exception occurs... However your solution is great and I've improved it with a cycle to support multiple formats at once without exceptions.

Comment: The *"how to use it"* part? That's in your code, where you want to serialize / deserialize the xml / objects.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe. Take care when sharing `dateFormat` state between threads.

Comment: @Burno, that is true. Vote up. However, it's thread safe in Java 8.